# My auto increment is not working and I have 10 digit length

Tags: mysql, sql

I used below query

```
ALTER TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 2013000000;
```

and i got error

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 2013000000' at line 2

I want 10 digit on auto_increment like my student Id on my school... can anyone help me... this is my user table

```
CREATE TABLE user(
   student_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
   ,   username varchar(15) NOT NULL
   ,   password varchar(15) NOT NULL
   ,   lastname varchar(15) NOT NULL
   ,   firstname varchar(15) NOT NULL
   ,   middlename varchar(15)
   ,   birthdate Date NOT NULL
   ,   gender varchar(6) NOT NULL
   ,   address varchar(30) NOT NULL
   ,   email varchar(50) NOT NULL
   ,   contact bigint(11) NOT NULL
   ,   marital_status varchar(15) NOT NULL
   ,   religion varchar(15) NOT NULL
   ,PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
);
```

then I used this

```
ALTER TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 2013000000;
```

and got error too.

all I want is `2013000000,2013000001,2013000002,2013000003,....`and so on

Comment: Isn't it `alter table TableName AUTO_INCREMENT = 2013000000;`

Comment: what? can you explain more cause i'm a bit newbie and searching

Comment: @JeraldPunx the table's name is required after the keyword `TABLE`, otherwise mysql does not know what table you want to alter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the table name:

```
ALTER TABLE user AUTO_INCREMENT = 2013000000;
            ^^^^
```

[Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Also, consider using a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). It may make life easier down the track, such as when a student's Id changes and they have existing data.

> The surrogate key is not derived from application data.